# Add CollectionView or ViewController to AlertView

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have a collection view like this: 
[image]

include textfields and buttons. I presented this view as a popover but the problem is I want the buttons to be on one line (button is also a cell of collection view) so there are 2 questions:

- How to change the buttons size to fit in one line but do not affect the textfield size
- Or how to add the collection view to an alert view so I have the action button easier??

Comment: If each button in separated cell, what about adding both buttons in the same cell?

Comment: FYI - Swift 2 is old and not supported any more. Swift 4 will be out soon. It's time to upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried implementing a `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`?

If not, try doing that and add the method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
// Implement the code here, check if the indexPaths belong to the buttons,
// And make it return a Size which has a width that is half of the CollectionView width (minus the padding between cells).
}
```

This lets the CollectionView place them side by side because it'll have enough space for both of them.

Comment: I tried that but the button is also a cell of the collection view so if I set the size it also affect to the size of a textfield :(

Comment: You shouldn't return the same CGSize for all cells. You should check the index path and return a smaller CGSize for the indexPaths that are for the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

to set the button in one line you need to Update your button Constraint.set both button width as Equal Width and align top,bottom constraint of both button.

Answer (score 0):

Pull both of your button to a stackView and draw only one button's width and height constraint and make the other follow the previous button's width and height. **stackView** will do the rest of the work.

Don't forget to add constraint for **stackView** though. :)

[image]

[image]

I just pull width and height constraint to the first button and from stackView view i set fill equally and interdistance 10

[image]

Comment: the button is added programatically, i don't use the storyboard :(

Comment: If you don't want to use storyboard, just add stackView programmatically.It's super easy and add your button into it.That's also easy dude. :)

Comment: the problem is the button is the UIView class I created for reusing in whole project and It's all have the same size and same constraint. I need to change only in this view, so any solution or I have to create new button?

Comment: write a func in ur custom class which will provide whole compact stack view as well as buttons.